# Is there some differences between the Vaulters and the Mezari Faction, except the skin?

Tags: endless-legend

Is there some differences between the Vaulters and the Mezari Faction, except the skin?

Here is a screenshot from the Faction Selection Menu. We can clearly see that both have the same traits.

**Vaulters**
[image: Vaulters]

**Mezari**
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mezari are a reskinned version of the Vaulters.

Originally, they were only available to owners of Dungeon of the Endless Founders Pack, but have since been made available to all players.

They may be developed into a full faction at some point, but it is unlikely.

Source: [Endless Legend Wiki](http://endlesslegend.gamepedia.com/Mezari)